# How can I push a struct into a priority_queue?

Tags: c++

How can I push this struct into a priority_queue?

```
struct Node {
    int first;
    int second;
    ll dis;
};

priority_queue < Node , vector <Node> , greater <Node> > q;
```

1.Does it right?

2.How can I push a value into queue?

I try to do like this but a lot of system bug:

```
q.push({u,v,0});
```

Answer (score 1):

What is "ll dis"? Which type is this? I suppose you shouldn't use "greater <Node>", instead define your own comparator to tell the program by which fields two Nodes should be compared. For example comparasion by field "first":

```
struct Node {
int first;
int second;
};

struct CompareByFirst {
bool operator()(Node const& n1, Node const& n2)
{
    // return "true" if "n1" is ordered before "n2", for example:
    return n1.first < n2.first;
}
};

priority_queue<struct Node, vector<struct Node>, CompareByFirst> pq;

struct Node n1={3,4} ,n2={5,6}, n3;

pq.push({1,2});
pq.push(n1);
pq.push({7,8});
pq.push(n2);

n3 = pq.top();
cout << "first " << n3.first <<" second " << n3.second << endl;
```

Based on [STL Priority Queue for Structure or Class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stl-priority-queue-for-structure-or-class/)

Comment: Thanks. My compiler didn't recognise it. And what is u and v that you are pushing into queue?

Comment: " ll " : means long long type

I uses #define ll long long to make it shorter.

Thanks to help me

Comment: hmm u and v just name of variables

Comment: @VladislavDanielKovalevsky `ll` and its ilk are the fruits of dreadful "competitive" programming site short-cuts to speed coding production at the price of near-illegibility. One of the many, many reasons those sites are absolutely poison to this industry. Oh, and bump on your answer.